# SQL server: retrieve grouped data from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Write SQL query based on info below Table `TRACK_BY_WCN`

```
CREATE TABLE CONTRACTOPS.TRACK_BY_WCN(
 CLAIM_TYPE     CHAR(1 BYTE)
,LOBID          CHAR(3 BYTE)
,WCN            VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
,RECEIVED_DATE  DATE
,FOUND_DATE     DATE
,CLAIM_NUMBER   VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) DEFAULT NULL
,HOLD_FLAG      CHAR(1 BYTE)      DEFAULT NULL
,LOCK_FLAG      VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)  DEFAULT NULL
,BILLED         NUMBER(16,2))
```

There are data in first 3 columns, `CLAIM_TYPE, LOBID,  WCN`, and there is program doing match by `WCN`. When found, the program will update all other fields. Please use one SQL to get count on how many `WCN` and how many matched claims, by claim type.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell what you are asking exactly. This might be what you want:

Count rows per `WCN`:

```
SELECT WCN, count(*) AS row_count
FROM   CONTRACTOPS.TRACK_BY_WCN
GROUP  BY WCN;
```

Count rows per `CLAIM_TYPE`

```
SELECT CLAIM_TYPE, count(*) AS row_count
FROM   CONTRACTOPS.TRACK_BY_WCN
GROUP  BY CLAIM_TYPE;
```

Count claims per `WCN` *and* `CLAIM_TYPE`

```
SELECT WCN, CLAIM_TYPE, count(*) AS row_count
FROM   CONTRACTOPS.TRACK_BY_WCN
GROUP  BY WCN, CLAIM_TYPE;
```